# Plugins menu doesn't appear in the admin panel

Tags: wordpress

I'm having a very simple problem. I'm new to WordPress and I'm trying to install a plugin.

Everyone says there's a "plugins" option on the sidebar-menu in the admin panel, but I don't see one!  I've looked for it in all the sub-menus too.

Whenever I try to search for this problem, I get results about creating a plugin to show on the admin menu.

Anyway, how can I get the plugins menu to show up?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The issue is almost certainly related to one of two things:

1) You don't have permissions (are you logged in as admin?)

OR

2) The theme (or a plugin) has disabled the plugins menu.

After you've checked to be sure that you are an administrator, then you should attempt to view this page:

http://www.yourdomain.com/wp-admin/plugins.php (replacing www.yourdomain.com with your site's domain name).

If it's accessible, then it's time to start exploring the theme (which theme are you using?) and possibly some of the plugins that might have disabled the menu item.

FYI, the method to remove dashboard menu items is covered here: http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-remove-menus-in-wordpress-dashboard

Comment: When I go to my-blog.com/wp-admin/plugins.php, I just get a blank white page. As far as I know, I have no other plugins installed.  Maybe I just need to reinstall my whole Wordpress installation?

Comment: @AndyJoslin - sounds like a fresh install could be good.  Alternatively, you can edit your wp-config.php file and edit the debug line to `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`, which should cause the blank page to actually output any issues that are going on.  Might allow you to troubleshoot the issue further.

Comment: @random_user_name, I have tried this and I am getting Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.... but I have an administrator account.

Answer (score 19):

If you did double check your file permissions (i.e. 755 for folders and 644 for wordpress files on Linux), please consider editing your `wp-config.php` file and change

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS',true);
```

to

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS',false);
```

The `Add New` option in `Plugins` menu will show up, also if you have internet connection, possible updates will be shown up.

[image]

Comment: I dont see that "Plugins"  menu itself between Appearance and the Users.  Is that available on WordPress free plan?

Comment: This saved it for me.

Answer (score 5):

This what I found looking for the same problem, I guess this is your situation also:

**If your site is hosted on** WordPress.com:

> Plugins: Plugins are tools used to extend the functionality of the WordPress platform. However, they are only applicable to self-hosted blogs and web sites using the WordPress.org software. **Plugins are not permitted here at WordPress.com for various security reasons.**

Answer (score 3):

On wordpress.com hosted sites, you don't have permission to install plugins. You must have an own wordpress installation to do that.

Answer (score 3):

I found this post searching for help with a similar issue with a self-hosted WordPress installation -- in this case it was a site that a friend had paid someone to make, but then took them off the work and asked me to help out.

There were several regular menu options missing -- it turned out to be down to a plugin called [Admin Menu Editor](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/) that the previous web guy had installed to limit the options available to my friend, so they wouldn't mess with things.

In this case I could access the options for Admin Menu Editor by going to `http://www.example.com/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=menu_editor`

Comment: I have the same issue, were you able to completely restore the admin menu? I tried disabling the plugin but it didn't work...

Comment: From memory, I think I undid any changes that Admin Menu Editor seemed to have been used to make first before removing the plugin -- which perhaps did a similar thing to the answer from ArchCodeMonkey below which directly changes the user's permissions. Sorry I can't be more helpful, I've moved on from this project now too!

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen that problem before. However, try either expanding all the current menu items to see if **"plugins"** are listed there, or try **deactivating** some/all of your plugins to see if one of the plugins are conflicting somehow and making your plugins menu **not** display.

Comment: How would he deactivate plugins if he can't get to the plugins page?

Comment: change the name of the plugin folder in wp-content/wp-plugins directory

Answer (score 2):

In one of my cases it turned out to be strictly file permission thing so apache users could not access the plugins directory.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I hit this problem at work recently with a WordPress site I inherited that had been originally developed by an external company. I tracked it down to the roles assigned to the user account. The *"admin"* account I had been given was actually assigned a restricted role that didn't have permission to access most of the settings.

Fortunately, I have access to the database so I was able to modify the assigned role directly. The default database prefix in WordPress is `wp` but you may need adjust these steps according to your own database.

First, find the `user_id` in the `wp_users` table for the account you want to modify and then run the following SQL against your WordPress database.

```sql
UPDATE wp_usermeta SET meta_value = "a:1:{s:13:""administrator"";b:1;}" WHERE user_id = {your_user_id} AND meta_key = "wp_capabilities";
UPDATE wp_usermeta SET meta_value = "10" WHERE user_id = {your_user_id} AND meta_key = "wp_user_level";
```

The next time you log in with that user account it should now have administrator privileges.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the **multisite** feature of Wordpress you will **only see the plugins menu if you are super admin**.

In the menu go to "My Sites" at the top of the page then click "Network Admin". (If you do not have this option you are not super admin.) Under "Network Admin" click "Dashboard" and then the plugins menu will appear. In your Network settings you can enable plugins for the sites.

The issue I was having was even trickier: No one was super admin. I fixed this by overwriting the "is_super_admin" function (simply returning true always) and then editing the settings as needed, before removing the overwrite again.

Answer (score 0):

If you install a local WordPress the Plugins sub menu will not appear for any of the sites you work.  Click My Sites area at the top of the page then click Network Admin and then click Dashboard.  The Plugins sub menu will appear there.  Then install new plugins and use it on sites on which you are working.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

For me, changing lines in **wp-config.php** worked. I changed:

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true); 
define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true);
```

to

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', false);
define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a couple of reasons for the same. Some of them are:-

Reason 1 - When the website is hosted on wordpress.com

Reason 2 - When the user is logged in with a non-admin account

Reason 3 - When the WordPress website/blog is a part of a multi-site-network and the network admin has disabled the plugin menu

Reason 4 - Plugins Conflict