# I do not have access to wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I need to have access to wordpress plugin but the plugin option is not in the menu, 
I also created an account on wordpress.ORG but still no result, my user role is Admin.

Comment: Is your site hosted on Wordpress.com?

Comment: no its hosted on wordpress.org

Comment: Wordpress.org does not host websites.

Comment: Okay, what's the URL of your site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not see the plugin option, chances are that your site is hosted on wordpress.**com**. You only have plugins available to you if you installed Wordpress on your own *separately hosted* web server (e.g., bluehost, godaddy, etc.). Source: http://en.support.wordpress.com/com-vs-org/

Comment: I have my own hosting, but have the same problem, I do not know how to get wordpress menu itself on my hosting cpanel.

Comment: Try looking at some of the suggestions in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194028/plugins-menu-doesnt-show-up-in-admin-panel

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
define( 'WP_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE', 'development' ); // development / staging / production
```

to your `wp-config.php`