# appearance and plugin not available in wordpress admin panel

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have created [online store](https://kisaanmaitreya.com) in word press. I logged in to admin panel with my admin login and i have verified that login is having admin rights also. Now,I want to change banner image and some font color but I can't see plugin and appearance tab in sidebar.please help. [screenshot of the admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVfgD.png)

[User admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiEvA.png)

Comment: are you sure that you are the admin and you have all rights to access? try checking with default admin login while you installed the wordpress, it seems you dont have complete permissions. In screenshot notification showing "Please notify administrator" showing you are not the admin

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194028/plugins-menu-doesnt-appear-in-the-admin-panel

Comment: Or may be this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/29411754/9945519

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An issue that some users have mentioned is that when they have entered their WordPress admin panel that they have been unable to locate their plugins menu from within the dashboard. This should appear about half way down the menu on the left of the screen below appearance and should have an icon that looks a little like a domestic plug. However for multisite users you may have to login as network admin to view this tab.

If however this tab is still missing you may wish to try the following:

1. See if the following exists:
   http://www.example.com/wp-admin/plugins.php (where you should
   replace example.com with the name of your site. If this does not
   exist then it is missing from your theme and needs to be replaced or
   you should swap your theme.
2. Also check in your FTP for a folder called wp-plugins where your plugins should reside, if this does not exist then you should create
   it.
3. If you do have a wp-plugins folder deactivate it by changing its name and then check your WordPress admin panel as your problem could
   be caused by a faulty plugin.

Comment: I tried https://kisaanmaitreya.com/wp-admin/plugins.php, I am getting "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page." this message.  @Priyanka Modi

Comment: once you can deactivated all plugin and test it. It's working or not. @praveenkumar

Comment: i checked in ftp and i see wp-plugins was not available. @Priyanka Modi

Answer (score 0):

> Are you sure that you are the admin and you have all rights to access?

Try checking with default admin login while you installed the wordpress, it seems you don't have complete permissions.

In your attached screenshot notification showing **"Wordpress update available. Please notify administrator"** clearly showing that you are not having the complete admin rights

Comment: i have edited my question and attached the screenshot of user screen with role defined, please check. @charan kumar